# Update Parse Installation objects using REST and only have deviceToken

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

When ios users agree to receive push notifications on their devices, we store the deviceToken in our backend DB.

We want to use channels to send pushes, but we can't update installation objects from the device itself, as it's not implemented. Most likely something we need to do and then handle all the subscribe/unsubscribe directly from the app itself.

But, is it at all possible/doable to subscribe/unsubscribe an installation object via REST when all we have is the deviceToken?

The only way I see it would be to pull all Installation objects from Parse using the master key, then traverse all deviceToken's to find the one deviceToken we need, and then use it's corresponding objectid to send an update call and subscribe/unsubscribe the device?

Is there a better way, or are we "forced" to move this into the native app itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to query the Installation class directly with the deviceToken and the master key via REST and then PUT an update.

https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-querying

https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints

https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-updating

Comment: Man I've been looking through these docs for hours and I just realized, with your help, that I can in fact query the _Installation class with the master key. Thanks!